# Multi Line Text input in NCurses/PDCurses ( C )

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I've been tinkering with Ncurses library for creating a small console application.
I'm on windows platform so I'm using PdCurses and everything is working fine.

But I've come to this simple problem: 
How do I create a function that will read or scan the a user input but will stop only when a certain button (say ALT_X) is pressed? (So it makes multiline since curses has fixed width and height and automatically move the buffer to the next line).

Thanks! :)

Edit: Only for C not C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built in multi-line field in curses/ncurses/pdcurses.  However ncurses includes the form library that provides multi-line fields.

I do not know if the form library will work with pdcurses.